# C# clone() with compiler enforced subtype recognition

Tags: c#, subtype, supertype

I don't think this is possible but maybe I'm wrong. I want to have a clone() in a supertype

```
public abstract class LivingThing {
    public abstract T clone<T>() where T : LDBASTobj;
}
```

but have the implementing subtypes return its own subtype, and have the compiler enforce this.    Something like this

```
// doesn’t compile
public class Animal : LivingThing  {
    public Animal clone() => new Animal();
}
```

This seems reasonable in principle because Animal is a substituteable (covariant?) subtype of LivingThing. The subtype code above is garbage, but I hope you can see what I mean. Is this possible?

(this question [C# clone from supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561902/c-sharp-clone-from-supertype) isn’t what I’m after).

Thanks

Comment: This sounds awfully similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65390181/9363973)

Comment: I did search before I posted and didn't find the linked answer, thanks. Should I delete the question as being just clutter, or would it be better to leave it? (Edit: I tried doing the "public abstract class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>" and almost got it!)

Comment: How you want to use the ```clone``` ?

Comment: @MichaelMao - I want the subtype info preserved so the compiler can pick up mistakes.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code how you want to use and what result you want to get

Comment: @MichaelMao: Thanks but no need. I have to implement a generic clone() anyway, and a type-specific clone on each subtype is going to be necessary anyway. A covariant clone would be nice but whatever. Just need to grind out the code anyway. Thanks.